# Time difference of closing AF_PACKET vs AF_INET?

Tags: c++, c, linux, sockets, network-programming

What is the reason for such time difference between closing sockets created as `AF_PACKET` and `AF_INET`? How can I reduce the closing time for `AF_PACKET`?

```cpp
sockfd = socket(AF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_RAW);
close(sockfd); // 60000 μs

sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_RAW);
close(sockfd); // 30 μs
```

---

code to reproduce the behavior:

```
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <time.h>

#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <net/if.h>

int main() {
    struct timeval time_start, time_end;
    int sockfd;

    if ((sockfd = socket(AF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_RAW)) == -1) {
        perror("socket error");
    } 

    gettimeofday(&time_start, NULL);
    close(sockfd);
    gettimeofday(&time_end, NULL);
    printf("close AF_PACKET: %ld \n", (time_end.tv_sec*1000000 + time_end.tv_usec) - (time_start.tv_sec*1000000 + time_start.tv_usec));


    if ((sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_RAW)) == -1) {
        perror("socket error");
    } 

    gettimeofday(&time_start, NULL);
    close(sockfd);
    gettimeofday(&time_end, NULL);
    printf("close AF_INET: %ld \n", (time_end.tv_sec*1000000 + time_end.tv_usec) - (time_start.tv_sec*1000000 + time_start.tv_usec));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: cannot reproduce; it would help if you showed a complete testcase.

Comment: @mosvy , I pasted the source code to reproduce the behavior. Same issue on RPi and a laptop.

Comment: Tried with linux 3.4.52:

`
    close AF_PACKET: 168
    close AF_INET: 94
`

Comment: With linux 4.4.34: `close AF_PACKET: 324 
close AF_INET: 91`.

Answer (score 1):

Logically not a significant difference for both of the close system calls

If I change your program like below,

`

```
int main() {
    struct timeval time_start, time_end;
    int sockfd;

    if ((sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_RAW)) == -1) {
        perror("socket error");
    }   

    gettimeofday(&time_start, NULL);
    close(sockfd);
    gettimeofday(&time_end, NULL);
    printf("close AF_INET: %ld \n", (time_end.tv_sec*1000000 + time_end.tv_usec) - (time_start.tv_sec*1000000 + time_start.tv_usec));

    if ((sockfd = socket(AF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_RAW)) == -1) {
        perror("socket error");
    }   

    gettimeofday(&time_start, NULL);
    close(sockfd);
    gettimeofday(&time_end, NULL);
    printf("close AF_PACKET: %ld \n", (time_end.tv_sec*1000000 + time_end.tv_usec) - (time_start.tv_sec*1000000 + time_start.tv_usec));

    return 0;
}`
```

I see the result as

```
shahul@shahul-VirtualBox:~/test$  ./a.out 
close AF_INET: 3471 
close AF_PACKET: 4 
shahul@shahul-VirtualBox:~/test$  ./a.out 
close AF_INET: 8 
close AF_PACKET: 7 
shahul@shahul-VirtualBox:~/test$  ./a.out 
close AF_INET: 8 
close AF_PACKET: 6 
shahul@shahul-VirtualBox:~/test$  ./a.out 
close AF_INET: 8 
close AF_PACKET: 5 
shahul@shahul-VirtualBox:~/test$  ./a.out 
close AF_INET: 9 
close AF_PACKET: 5
```

similarly, if I change as below,

```
int main() {
    struct timeval time_start, time_end;
    int sockfd;

    if ((sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_RAW)) == -1) {
        perror("socket error");
    }

    gettimeofday(&time_start, NULL);
    close(sockfd);
    gettimeofday(&time_end, NULL);
    printf("close AF_INET: %ld \n", (time_end.tv_sec*1000000 + time_end.tv_usec) - (time_start.tv_sec*1000000 + time_start.tv_usec));

    if ((sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_RAW)) == -1) {
        perror("socket error");
    } 

    gettimeofday(&time_start, NULL);
    close(sockfd);
    gettimeofday(&time_end, NULL);
    printf("close AF_INET: %ld \n", (time_end.tv_sec*1000000 + time_end.tv_usec) - (time_start.tv_sec*1000000 + time_start.tv_usec));

    if ((sockfd = socket(AF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_RAW)) == -1) {
        perror("socket error");
    }   

    gettimeofday(&time_start, NULL);
    close(sockfd);
    gettimeofday(&time_end, NULL);
    printf("close AF_PACKET: %ld \n", (time_end.tv_sec*1000000 + time_end.tv_usec) - (time_start.tv_sec*1000000 + time_start.tv_usec));



    return 0;
}
```

result as below,

```
shahul@shahul-VirtualBox:~/test$  ./a.out 
close AF_INET: 6 
close AF_INET: 3 
close AF_PACKET: 3 
shahul@shahul-VirtualBox:~/test$  ./a.out 
close AF_INET: 8 
close AF_INET: 4 
close AF_PACKET: 5 
shahul@shahul-VirtualBox:~/test$  ./a.out 
close AF_INET: 8 
close AF_INET: 4 
close AF_PACKET: 4 
shahul@shahul-VirtualBox:~/test$  ./a.out 
close AF_INET: 8 
close AF_INET: 4 
close AF_PACKET: 4
```

conclusion:
Basically, first close call taking more time,
perhaps time is taken to map the **close system call function for the first time**.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately, I can not confirm that for my devices: Raspberry Pi (Raspbian 9.4. 4.14.17) and a laptop (Ubuntu 17.04, 4.10.0). Closing time disparities remain the same even after multiple open-close cycles.